# Why is the style property empty of this HTMLStyleElement?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, xml-parsing

I have an html string that I getting from a backend server.

I am trying to view css properties and extract the value of a first occurrence of a background-color in a HTMLStyleElement. However the format of the HTMLStyleElement is different than I expected.

[image]

How might I find the first occurrence of the property in the css without searching through the string if possible?

Comment: Why don't you want to search through the string? How else would you find it?

Comment: The style property is empty because that shows the inline styles of the element, and there aren't any. e.g. If you had `<style style="display:block">...</style>`. display:block would be in the style property.